# QThread always one thread left behind

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

This is my thread:

```
class calThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    calThread(QList<int> number);
    ~calThread();
    void run();
    QList<int> cal(QList<int> input);

signals:
    void calFinished(QList<int> result);   
};

void calThread::run()
{
     output = cal(number);
     emit calFinished(output);
     sleep(1);
}
```

This is how I call the thread:

```
    calThread* worker3 = new calThread(numberList);
    connect(worker3, SIGNAL(calFinished(List<int>)), this, SLOT(handleResult(List<int>)));
    connect(worker3, SIGNAL(finished()), worker3, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    worker3->start();
```

I have a large list of input. I divide the list into four equal sized list and put them into individual thread to calculate. They are namely `worker0` to `worker3`.

Every time the program runs, the four threads start at similar time. But there is always one thread that returns much much slower. For example, it takes about 2 minutes for first 3 threads to finish, the fourth thread takes maybe 5 minutes to return.

But all thread should have same number of items and same complexity to calculate.

Why is there always a thread left behind?

#### Debug output:

```
inputThread0 item numbers: 1736 
inputThread1 item numbers: 1736 
inputThread2 item numbers: 1736 
inputThread3 item numbers: 1737 

"20:29:58" Thread 0 Thread ID 0x7f07119df700
"20:29:58" Thread 3 Thread ID 0x7f06fc1d3700
"20:29:58" Thread 1 Thread ID 0x7f06fd1d5700
"20:29:58" Thread 2 Thread ID 0x7f06fc9d4700
"20:29:58" Thread 0 Thread ID 0x7f07119df700
"20:29:58" Thread 1 Thread ID 0x7f06fd1d5700
….............................
//Most of them are Thread 0,1,2 afterward
….............................
"20:29:58" Thread 1 Thread ID 0x7f06fd1d5700
// This is last Thread from thread 0,1,or2
// It takes less than one second to finish
"20:29:59" Thread 3 Thread ID 0x7f06fc1d3700
"20:29:59" Thread 3 Thread ID 0x7f06fc1d3700
"20:29:59" Thread 3 Thread ID 0x7f06fc1d3700
"20:29:59" Thread 3 Thread ID 0x7f06fc1d3700
….................................
// Only Thread 3 left
"20:30:17" Thread 3 Thread ID 0x7f06fc1d3700
// This last thread takes 19 second to finish
```

Comment: How many core do you have on your computer?
did you try to print a debug information inside your cal function for each item in the input list just to see what may happen?

Comment: Looks like your task would be handled well by the mapReduce , take a look at http://blog.qt.io/blog/2007/04/26/mapreduce-in-qt-concurrent/

Comment: @Q-B I am using a quad core cpu. The debug result has been post.

Comment: You do not have deterministic barriers (wich anyway don't make any guarantee on order of execution of single tasks) like in PLINQ.

Comment: This is poor design. You force a scheme where work can only be done by the "right" thread. Instead, design things so that whatever thread happens to get CPU time can do the work that needs to be done. That way, you'll never get into a situation where all the work has to be done by one thread.

Comment: The fact that one thread takes significantly longer to finish than the other threads took in total from start to finish suggests something wrong with your code. Perhaps some quirk makes your code much less efficient when only one thread is running (perhaps some wrongheaded attempt at "fairness"). Or perhaps you aren't really dividing the work evenly.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I admit that it is a poor design. I will make improvement by adding a thread controller so that threads query for new job when they finished the current. Initially I think my method will be more efficient because I don't need to lock the input resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Why is there always a thread left behind?"

Why not? Thread scheduling is completely on the whim of the OS. There is no guarantee at all that any threads will get any sort of a "fair share" of any CPU resources. You need to assign small chunks of work and have them automatically distributed across the worker threads. `QtConcurrent::run` and the QtConcurrent framework in general offers a trivial way of getting that done. As long as the chunks of work passed to `run`, `mapReduce`, etc. are reasonably sized (say take between 0.1 and 1s), all of the threads in the pool will be done within a couple tenths of a second of each one.

A partial explanation for your observed behavior is that a thread that already runs on a given core is more likely to be rescheduled on the same core to utilize the warm caches there. If there are three out of four cores that run your threads almost continuously, the fourth thread often ends up sharing the core with your GUI thread, and will necessarily run slower if the GUI is not idle. If the GUI thread is busy processing the results from the other threads, it is not unexpected that the computation thread would be starved on that core. This is actually the most power- *and* time-efficient way to schedule the threads, with least amount of overhead.

As long as you give the threads small chunks of work to do, and distribute them on as-ready basis - as `QtConcurrent` does - it will also lead to smallest wall clock runtimes. If the scheduler was forcing "fair" reschedules, your long-running threads would all finish roughly at the same time, but would take more time *and* power to finish the job. Modern schedulers enable you to run your jobs most efficiently, but you must set the jobs up to take advantage of that.

In a way, your scheduler is helping you improve your code to be more resource-efficient. That's a good thing.

Comment: In fact, the gui is always busy because my threads always send signal to the gui for showing progress.